# Custom gridview adapter is slow or moves elements around

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am trying to create a gridview with images and text. 
I have this code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View gridView;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_text);
        textView.setText(titles[position]);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_picture);
        try {
            if (imageUrls[position].equals("null")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultpic);
            }else{
                Bitmap bitmap = new setImage().execute(imageUrls[position]).get();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "EXCEPTION:" + e.toString());
        }
    }
    else{
        gridView = convertView;
    }
    return gridView;
}
```

but when using this code, some elements of the gridview switch places.
Then I tried changing it. I ended up with this code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View gridView;
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
    }else{
        gridView = convertView;
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_text);
    textView.setText(titles[position]);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_picture);
    try {
        if (imageUrls[position].equals("null")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultpic);
        }else{
            Bitmap bitmap = new setImage().execute(imageUrls[position]).get();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "EXCEPTION:" + e.toString());
    }
    return gridView;
}
```

this works, but the gridview is really slow and laggy. So my question is, how do you make a gridview that's not slow and doesn't switch elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of switching was probably caused by the fact that in the first code you were not setting the fields of the recycled view every time, thus causing the old data to be shown (that's what happened to me anyway in the past).
I suggest also to take a look at the ViewHolder pattern for smoother scrolling ([ViewHolder Pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)).

I think the mainperformance problem however is a blocking call in the getView method: the major suspect I see is the

```
setImage().execute(imageUrls[position]).get();
```

line, especially that get() at the end seems to be waiting for a task to finish. If that were the case, I would reccommend the reading of this series of articles [Displaying bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), which explains also how to deal with bitmaps in listviews.

Comment: Thanks! Caching the bitmaps was the solution. I was looking everywhere for this!

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also use ImageLoader to load images in imageView.It can load URL or local file image.Why am suggesting this one is it perform the assigned task asynchrounusly without affecting the main thread.For better performance use ViewHolder as well as  Image Loader to load images.
ImageLoader library is available in GitHub you can download from it.

click here to download the library
```

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader